# Why are the password fields filled on my Wordpress User Edit Page?

Tags: wordpress, passwords

In Wordpress, when I go to edit a user from the admin side (user-edit.php), the password fields are already filled in.  This causes the users's password to be reset if I edit any other field and click update user.

The password fields are filled with a whole string of random characters.

My site didn't used to do this.  I'm seeing it on WP 4.1, but I have other 4.1 installs that don't have this problem.

I deactivated all the plugins, and it still didn't solve the problem.
What is causing the password to be pre-populated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused if you are using Pressable, by Pressable's "Never Email Passwords" plugin.

The Readme file for the plugin states:

**Never Email Passwords**

NEP is a WordPress plugin that does three things:

- Hides the "Send this password to the new user by email" checkbox on
  the dashboard's "Add New User" page.
- Autofills the password fields with a 64-character string from
  wp_generate_password.
- Emails a password reset link to the new user.

https://github.com/pressable/never-email-passwords

.

Pressable has many "Must-Use" plugins, stored in the mu-plugins folder, that cannot be deactived from the admin section of Wordpress.

See the list of pre-installed plugins here:

http://kb.pressable.com/faq/why-are-there-plugins-pre-installed-on-my-site/

**.To Fix:**

Unfortunately, Pressable does not allow you to remove this plugin. If you delete it, it will re-install itself.
I found that I could edit the javascript file in the mu-plugins/never-email-passwords/js/ folder, and simply comment it all out.  However, my changes could be over-written.

I made a quick plugin based on Never Email Passwords to correct this. If you wish you use it, just drop it in mu-plugins.

Here's the link:
https://github.com/dwlorimer/nep-fightback